# c# - How to read back textbox and add 1 each time

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a clothing sale GUI for my friends clothing shop. So when I type in a price and number of items, it'll display the total price, calculate the discount and calculate the amount due. And then when I enter a new price and # of items for the next customer, It repeats the process. My code doesn't update the number of transactions and total sales($) it just resets it. I want to return the previous number of transactions and total sales and add it to the next calculation. Please help guys!

```
        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double numberofitems;
        double price;
        double totalprice;
        double discount;
        double amountdue;
        double totalsales;
        double transactions = 0;



        // Total Price
        numberofitems = double.Parse(txtBoxNumberOfItems.Text);
        price = double.Parse(txtBoxPrice.Text);
        totalprice = numberofitems * price;
        txtBoxTotalPrice.Text = totalprice.ToString();

        // Discount
        discount = totalprice * 30 / 100;
        txtBoxDiscount.Text = discount.ToString();

        // Amount Due
        amountdue = totalprice - discount;
        txtBoxAmountDue.Text = amountdue.ToString();

        // Total Sales
        totalsales = amountdue;
        txtBoxTotalSales.Text = totalsales.ToString();


        // Number of Transactions
        transactions++;
        txtBoxTransactions.Text = transactions.ToString();

    }

        // Clear button
    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBoxNumberOfItems.Text = "";
        txtBoxPrice.Text = "";
        txtBoxTotalPrice.Text = "";
        txtBoxDiscount.Text = "";
        txtBoxAmountDue.Text = "";
        txtBoxTotalSales.Text = "";
        txtBoxTransactions.Text = "";

    }
        // Exit Button
    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
```

Comment: It is unclear what your question is.  Perhaps add more detail and be very specific about what it is you are asking.

Comment: So when I type in a price and number of items, it'll display the total price, calculate the discount and calculate the amount due. And then when I enter a new price and # of items for the next customer, It repeats the process how ever I want it to add to the previous number of total sales($) and number of transactions

Comment: It it an asp.net web form? Since you are writing totalSales and transactions every time to the UI, you can read it back before adding for new product

Comment: It is a windows form applications. How can i read it back so it adds the new product to the old one? I think you understand what i'm trying to say haha

Comment: Where is the code that you clear a session?

Comment: Posted the whole code

Comment: without running the code myself, I suspect that the issues are happening because you've declared all your variables inside the method. They all get reset to 0 to start off with. Make the ones you need class variables and you should be sweet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK if I understand your issue correctly transactions and total sales are getting reset, and as I mentioned before, it's because you set those variables in the `btnCalculate_Click()` method. So by default, every time you click on the calculate button they get reset to `0`. This is due to variable scope, google it. To fix the problem, all you will need to do is make `transactions` and `totalsales` as class variables instead of the local method variables you have now.

```
// now class variables and can be seen by the whole class
double transactions = 0;
double totalsales;

private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // method variables which can only be seen by this method
    double numberofitems;
    double price;
    double totalprice;
    double discount;
    double amountdue;

    // Total Price
    numberofitems = double.Parse(txtBoxNumberOfItems.Text);
    price = double.Parse(txtBoxPrice.Text);
    totalprice = numberofitems * price;
    txtBoxTotalPrice.Text = totalprice.ToString();

    // Discount
    discount = totalprice * 30 / 100;
    txtBoxDiscount.Text = discount.ToString();

    // Amount Due
    amountdue = totalprice - discount;
    txtBoxAmountDue.Text = amountdue.ToString();

    // Total Sales
    totalsales += amountdue;
    txtBoxTotalSales.Text = totalsales.ToString();

    // Number of Transactions
    transactions++;
    txtBoxTransactions.Text = transactions.ToString();
}
```

Comment: omg you're a genius, thank you so much! this solved my problem :)

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
string objTextBox = t.Text;
```